# flutter: tinder like swipe feedback animation

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

im working on a tinder swipe similar app with flutter. im using the appinio_swiper: ^2.0.0 packege for it.

i want now to have a tinder like feedback animation after swipe left or right for like or dislike.

tried it with gestureDetector, but if i use it, the cards don't move anymore after that. any other ideas or solutions? would be grateful for any kind of help.

here is my code:

```
                AppinioSwiper(
                  loop: false,
                  onSwipe: _swipe,
                  allowUnswipe: true,
                  controller: swipeController,
                  cardsCount: users.length,
                  swipeOptions: AppinioSwipeOptions.horizontal,
                  cardsBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SwipeCard(
                      user: users[index],
                      onTapInfo: () {
                        showBottomSheet(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (context) {
                            return UserSwipeDetailsScreen(
                              user: users[index],
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      onTapShare: () {},
                      onTapUndo: () {
                        setState(() {
                          swipeController.unswipe();
                        });
                      },
                      onTapWarning: () {},
                    );
                  },
                )
```

Comment: I think i want the same thing, i've opened a Github issue here: https://github.com/appinioGmbH/flutter_packages/issues/81

Comment: they released a new version and closed the github issue ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with a different package: [swipable_stack](https://pub.dev/packages/swipable_stack).

which is basically the same as appinio_swiper.

there u can define a overlayBuilder

```
SwipableStack(
  overlayBuilder: (context, properties) {
    final opacity = min(properties.swipeProgress, 1.0);
    final isRight = properties.direction == SwipeDirection.right;
    return Opacity(
      opacity: isRight ? opacity : 0,
      child: CardLabel.right(),
    );
  },
)
```